# Resteasy does not find ExceptionMapper provider

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, provider

I have tried a lot of things to make this work, but it is not working anyway. Also, I don't find proper documentation about this.
I am trying to implement a `CustomExceptionMapper` for my `CustomException` type. The `CustomException` is thrown correctly, but it is not catched.

I thought that annotating the `CustomExceptionMapper` with `@Provider` was enough, but it isnot detected.
I have tried to allow scanning in web.xml, but I've found this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1739 . I am using 7.0.1 Final. Probably the solution is changing of version, but this decision is not up to me.

I have also found that you can try to override the `getClasses()` or `getSingletons` method and add there your `CustomExceptionMapper`, but it is just not detecting it.

How my Application class looks like:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("/service")
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(TestExceptionMapper.class); 
        return classes;

    }
}
```

And the Mapper

```
@Provider
public class TestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<TestException> {

    public Response toResponse(TestException ex) {
       //something, but I cannot reach it.
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mycompany.rest.exceptions.TestExceptionMapper</param-value>        
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.rest.application.myApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

And the service which is being called through URL:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/somePath")
public class someService {

    @GET //this should be post, but for testing I'm using get
    @Path("/some/update/someth")
    @Produces()
    public String updateSometh(@NotNull @QueryParam("key") String key, @QueryParam(value = "somethID") Long somethID) throws TestException {
       // ....
    }
```

If you call this with the correct parameters, it works. But if you put a bad parameter, it does not.
I would like to say too that the application is working, but I just wanted to add the Mappers.

Comment: Where is your code that throws `TestException`?

Comment: I am testing what happens when I put a Long parameter with a wrong value (like 120sd instead of just a number). The exception is thrown there, because it cannot be parsed.

Comment: Please show the resource code where are you doing this test. I suspect is a problem there as I have a very similar configuration to yours and exception mappers work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception mappers works for the exceptions thrown from the body of your resource method. If you modify your resource to throw a `TestException`:

```
public String updateSometh(@NotNull @QueryParam("key") String key, 
            @QueryParam(value = "somethID") Long somethID) throws TestException {
   throw new TestException();
}
```

the mapper should catch the exception. The problem is in the way you tested.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. But anyway, isn't it possible to catch exceptions that do not even arrive to the body?

Comment: These exceptions might have different causes that you usually can deal with. For example, in your case you can use a `ValidatorAdaptor` to validate the `somethID` parameter. I think you also need to make it a `String` instead of a `Long`.

Comment: I will try with the validator approach, but having to parse by myself seems not a good approach when if can do it automatically

Comment: In fact the `ValidatorAdaptor` is suitable for more complex validations, maybe in this simple case is better to let Resteasy return the default `Bad Request` response.

Comment: if RESTeasy is configured to scan all resources, is it necessary to have `context-param`?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. How can I catch Exceptions that have been thrown before reaching the body of the method ? (for example a failed bean validation)

Answer (score 2):

does your web.xml have the context-param for resteasy providers?

something like this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>packagename.TestExceptionMapper</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: how can I register several  Exception Mappers for different type of Exception in RestEasy?

Answer (score 2):

You can also register a custom ExceptionMapper in your javax.ws.rs.core.Application class by overriding the classes() method like so:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    // other resource classes ...

    classes.add(CustomExceptionMapper.class);
    return classes;
  }
}
```

The ExceptionMapper itself can use java.lang.Exception as Type parameter to handle any kind of exception.

```
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    //...
}
```